# PHP echo function in BuddyPress to Hyperlink to Member Profile Pages

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

When I first setup BuddyPress on my site, root profiles were enabled. Basically, if a registered user wanted to edit the account settings of their profile, the URL where they could do that would be: "domain.com/username". However, if you typed in "domain.com/members/username" in your browser, you would get the exact same page.

I decided I did not want root profiles enabled because I preferred the URL to be: "domain.com/members/username", so based on this guide (http://codex.buddypress.org/extending-buddypress/changing-internal-configuration-settings), I  edited the code in functions.php to be like this:

```
    define ( 'BP_ENABLE_ROOT_PROFILES', false );
```

However, in header.php, where my navigation is located, the PHP function is still linking to the root profile that I wanted disabled. This is what it looks like:

```
    <a href="<?php echo bp_loggedin_user_domain() ?>">Profile</a>
```

I am trying to figure out how I can change the function so that it links to: "domain.com/members/username" instead of "domain.com/username".

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the `define ( 'BP_ENABLE_ROOT_PROFILES', false );` in your function.php file.

Because the Buddypress default provide domain.com/members/username.

And also please check the wp-config.php file if above code is there just remove it

Please try this